# Exporting more than 1 default in Next _app.tsx

Tags: typescript, react-redux, next.js, next-i18next

I came to this tricky situation, where I need to "export 2 defaults in my Next _app file (using typescript).

I started to export it for Redux, which I am using in my app

```
export default wrapper.withRedux(MyApp);
```

But now I need to translate my app with using next-i18next, where I am importing appWithTranslation and I also need to export it

```
import { appWithTranslation } from 'next-i18next';
export default appWithTranslation(MyApp);
```

Is it possible to have 2 export defaults somehow ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible, but you can do either `wrapper.withRedux(appWithTranslation(MyAppp))` or `appWithTranslation(wrapper.withRedux(MyApp))` (not sure which order you need), so you will  get one default export both - with redux and with translation.